# Why are blackberry plants typically named for Native American tribes?

Tags: fruits, terminology, berries, blackberry

Whenever I see blackberry plants for sale, it always seem like they're named for a native American tribe. There's Navaho, Apache, Arapaho, Kiowa. The only ones I know of that don't follow this trend are the triple crown blackberries.

Is there a reason for this trend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you happen to be seeing mostly (likely due to locale) the output of **one breeding program** and that is their theme. [Looking here, page 24 to 26](http://host31.spidergraphics.com/nra/doc/Fair%20Use%20Web%20PDFs/NRAES-35_Web.pdf), that would appear to be Arkansas; and many more names other than Triple Crown (from Maryland) that are not in that theme show up. Illini, (guess where that's from) Thornfree,  Doyle Thornless, Black Satin, Chester Thornless, Hull, Lawton, Darrow...

Comment: Good theory. I sometimes have a hard time tracking down the origins of some cultivars.